# Google Calendar API update event back to site issue - php

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I am working on a project using google calendar API. I managed to sync the events from my site to gcal api, when i try to loop the events from gcal and see which ones changed and make the changes on my site, page loads slow.

My question, is there an easy way to update the event from Google Calendar back to my site without loading the page slow?

I was thinking about using cronjobs, but i can't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger this event from client side using Javascript after page was loaded, but keep in mind to add some ddos protection.

The other way is to have a node js server running on the backend in parallel which would have a scheduled task to do this, but that is overengineering replacement of cronjob solution.

Also this could help you - just create a channel to watch for event changes:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#receiving-notifications

Comment: How would they ddos if i am using javascript to send requests?

Comment: I was meaning that you have to create an endpoint at backend which will make request to Google API to grab all the events and response which data should be updated on the client side.

When the page loaded the ajax request would be sent to this backend endpoint. But somebody could ddos this endpoint using 3rd party tools causing numerous calls to the Google Calendar API from your backend so you will exceed the calls limit or overload your server if you're planning to perform some queries to the database in this endpoint logic besides performing the calls to the Google Calendar API.